# sessionStorage setItem is deleting previous keys

Tags: reactjs, sessionstorage

I am trying to save a simple item into `sessionStorage` so in order to achieve this I am simply writing  `sessionStorage.setItem('usr', JSON.stringify(data.user));` 
and later I need to save a different key pair so I write `sessionStorage.setItem('u_p', JSON.stringify(page.data));` but this action will result in the deletion of the previous key so I end it up with only the key `'u_p'` and the key `'usr'` gets deleted.

I tried writing in the same document  `sessionStorage.setItem('test1', 'value'); sessionStorage.setItem('test2', 'value');`
 to check if I maybe clearing the `sessionStorage` in other part of my code but still will save only the last one listed.

Why is this could be happening?
Is there a way I can debug this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Isthe domain same when you are setting sessionStorage.setItem('test1', 'value');  and sessionStorage.setItem('test2', 'value'); If the url is changing, domain is changing , hence it will not give you the old keys which you set earlier.

Comment: Hope you have checked the developer console->Application tab-> Session storage to see that really the values are getting replaced?

Comment: right is exactly the place I was looking at but as soon I create a new key pair element the previous seems to get deleted but not really because if I `console.log` the `sessionStorage ` they all are there just not in the console to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after stack26 answer I just `console.log(sessionStorage)` and indeed all the key pairs were present in there.

So the conclusion is that the key pairs weren't stacking visually in the console for me to see them but definitely, they were saving it correctly and I can access them anytime.

Thank you